# How to port Ubuntu touch to XPERIA Go?

Tags: system-installation

I want to install a Ubuntu touch on my Xperia Go smartphone, but I can't find any tutorial..
Can anyone create tutorial how to install or port it?
Thanks!

Comment: and see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Comment: i think about unofficial Ubuntu Touch

Comment: Please try Google first, the very first result was a compiled port for your phone http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2219740